# I have a list of grobs. How do I make a glist or gtree?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I have a `list` of Grobs

```
my_grob_list = list(
  grid::pointsGrob(1, 2, 16, gp = grid::gpar(col = "red")),
  grid::pointsGrob(3, 4, 16, gp = grid::gpar(col = "blue"))
)
```

How do I create a `gList` or `gTree` from that? Calling `gList(my_grob_list)` or `gTree(my_grob_list)` throws an error because it's expecting grobs.

Comment: `gTree(my_grob_list)` didn't throw any errors for me. You could try `do.call(grid::gList, my_grob_list)` for the glist option.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like something else wasn't happy with gTree, but `do.call(grid::gList, my_grob_list)` did the trick.